# A Metallica haiku -- Who am I?

Tags: riddle, poetry, haiku

> Administers food
>
> Does De Re Metallica
>
> Eponymous towns

Who am I?

Comment: This puzzle deserves more recognition. A haiku is not very easy to construct.

Comment: @CodeNewbie How do you figure?

Comment: @CodeNewbie Haikus are easy / You just stop writing after / Seventeen sylla-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing

> Herbert Hoover

*Administers food*

> He was the head of the U.S. Food Administration

*Does De Re Metallica*

> He translated the book

*Eponymous towns*

> So-called Hoovervilles during the great depression